# Cherrypy: my ajax call seems to be sometimes rejected whereas cherrypy function not finished

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, cherrypy

I'm facing a problem since a couple of days.

I have a web application that runs in firefox (html, jquery), and business stuff is done by cherrypy (the application is local, firefox and the cherrypy run on the same machine). All of that run on fedora25.
The web application calls function on cherrypy with jquery ajax.

A step of my application is HDD diagnostic with SMART. The call is quite long (about 1 minute)

### On "html" side:

The web app performs an ajax call like that:

```
$.ajax({'url': 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/launch_hdd_diag?hdd_index=SYSTEM'})
    .done(one_hdd_diag_done)
    .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown )
          { 
              alert("text status = [" + textStatus + "]\njqXHR.state() = [" + jqXHR.state() + "]");
              log_error("Unexpected error while SYSYTEM hdd diag.");
              one_hdd_diag_done({"status": hdd_diag_result_TECHNICAL_ERROR, "disk_index": "SYSTEM" });
          });
```

### On cherrypy side

Simplified code:

```
@cherrypy.expose
@cherrypy.config(**{'tools.cors.on': True})
@cherrypy.tools.json_in()
@cherrypy.tools.json_out()
def launch_hdd_diag(self, hdd_index):
    device_path = ... # here we get /dev/sda from hdd_index, for instance.
    subprocess.Popen("sudo smartctl --test=short " + device_path, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate() # short call
    is_running = True
    while is_running:
        is_running = is_short_test_running(device_name) # we have a short Popen(...).communicate() in that function
        time.sleep(5)
    status = get_test_result(device_name)
    log("finished")
    return {"disk_index": hdd_index, "status": status}
```

### What I observe and cannot explain

Sometimes (I don't know when...) the ajax call ends as fail **before** launch_hdd_diag cherrypy function finishes.
The alert popup shows: textStatus = "Error" and jqXHR.state() = "rejected".
I observe that :

- in the logs: because log_error("Unexpected error... is logged before log("finished") is.
- in the cherrypy calls output: I observed the GET request is logged by cherrypy after completion, and I can see the ajax fail log 30 seconds before cherrypy logs the end of the GET request.

The headers of a success call and a rejected call are strictly the same (firefox developper tools).

---

My questions:

Do you have some debbuging tips? would you need additional infos? Can you explain that?

I don't have anymore (I tried cache on/off, I tried timeouts, I tried to launch cherrypy in a console, in a nohup process, whithout console...)
I'm going to change my code so ajax queries are short: I'll move the while from cherrypy to web (polling from jquery side...), but I'm not very confident about robustness of this workaround because I don't understand the current behavior.

---

### Some additional info if needed:

Here is how I launch cherrypy server:

```
config = {
    'global' : {
        'server.socket_host' : '127.0.0.1',
        'server.socket_port' : 8000,
        'server.thread_pool' : 50,
        'response.timeout'   : 7200,
        'log.error_file'     : "/my/error/log",
    }
}

def cors():
    if cherrypy.request.method == 'OPTIONS':
        # preflign request 
        # see http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#cross-origin-request-with-preflight-0
        cherrypy.response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'POST'
        cherrypy.response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = 'content-type'
        cherrypy.response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin']    = '*'
        # tell CherryPy no avoid normal handler
        return True
    else:
        cherrypy.response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'

cherrypy.tools.cors = cherrypy._cptools.HandlerTool(cors)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cherrypy.quickstart(App(), '/', config)
```

Thank you very very much for any help.

Comment: What is the HTTP status code of response on failure?

Comment: That's what is very strange: sometimes the ajax fails before request is done, and 30 seconds later, the HTTP request is OK (code 200)

Comment: When you say that you tried cache on/off – does it mean ajax cache disabling? `$.ajax({cache: false, url: '...'})`

Comment: Yes, exactly. And I also tried on cherrypy side by setting 'tools.caching': False on global configuration. I also suspect the keep-alive connection (I read about that, it may disturb cherrypy, but I didn't investiguate more on that idea, because it was not simple to close connection after request...)

Comment: Humm... after writing my previous comment, I remember that after disabling the cache on ajax, the request on cherrypy failed, because jquery add a _ parameter, with a timestamp as value, or something like that. And I didn't have the time to test with this extra _ parameter... (end of day, time boxing, project deadline... you know). If I find some time at home, I'll try to write a simple project to produce again, and test this cache disabling and see the impact. FYI, I worked-around the problem by making long call asynchronous: just trig them, and poll (ajax -> cherrypy) for completion.